# How do I turn flash "on" instead of "auto" on iPhone camera in iOS14?

Tags: ios, camera

Before iOS14, one could keep flash on permanently by clicking on the flash icon in the upper left of the screen and setting flash to "on". Now, clicking on the flash icon only gives the options of "auto" or "off".

How do I set flash to "on" when taking a photo or video?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can swipe up from the bottom of the photo/video preview to bring up additional options, including the ability to set flash to "on". You can then swipe down to hide the options.

When taking a photo (as opposed to a video), you also have the option of using the arrow at the top of the screen to toggle the options.